# ps comm format always cuts the process name

Tags: bash, ps

I am trying to invoke `ps -o comm:1024 --pid 1391 --cols 1024 -w` in the hope of getting the full process name (and only that), but I always end up with this

```
COMMAND
notification-ar
```

while the process name is instead notification-area-applet. I also tried all combinations of -w, --cols and : formatter. cmd and args give the full path and arguments of the process. I might be able to get the process name from these, but still...

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/717919/how-to-prevent-ps-from-truncating-the-process-name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `comm` field (also `/proc/$pid/comm`) is **limited *by the kernel* to 16 bytes** total (15 characters + terminating NUL byte).

If the system is Linux and you own the process (or are root), you can obtain the executable path by following **`/proc/$pid/exe`** using the `readlink` command.

Otherwise, you will have to use the `cmd` field (aliases `args`, `command`). On Linux it's taken from **`/proc/$pid/cmdline`** (which is NUL-separated), so you can also use `cut -d "" -f 1 /proc/$pid/cmdline`.

Beware that **both** `cmdline` and `comm` can be changed by the process itself.

Comment: I take it that this means that there is no way to get the full, unaltered command?